# how to insert a - symbol before the last alphabet in a string using regex pattern in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, performance, regexp-replace

hi i have a value for example 023A i need to replace or format it to 23-A by removing leading 0, it is 123A it should be 123-A
can anyone help me out in java regex how to do this?

Comment: Please describe more clearly the replacement logic here.

Comment: input.replaceAll("^(0*)(.*)(\\w)$", "$2-$3");

Comment: Assuming the strings of interest consist of one or more digits followed by a capital letter, you could replace the match of the regular expression `\b0*(\d+)([A-Z])\b` with `"$1-$2"`, `$1` and `$2` being the contents of capture groups 1 and 2. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/MY7lhW/1/)

Comment: @CarySwoveland the tooltip for the _add a comment_ link says: _Avoid answering questions in comments._ I think your comment is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote some code which is specific to the pattern you asked, hope it help.

Code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo 
{

static String format(String str)
{
    String string = "";
        
    try
    {
     //remove every non-numerical character at the start of string, if there is
     //remove every zero at the start of string   
     while(str.startsWith("0") || Character.isLetter(str.charAt(0))) {
        str = str.substring(1);
     }
         
     //Gets the index of firstmost non-numerical character
     int index = 0;
     boolean valueFound = false;
     for(int i = 0; i <= str.length() -1; i++)
     {
      if(Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) {
        index = i;
        valueFound = true;
        break;
      }    
     }    
         
     if(valueFound)
     {
      string = str.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(index)), "-" + 
      String.valueOf(str.charAt(index)));
     }
    }  
    catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();} 
        
    return string;   
} 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input a combination : "); 
        String line = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input   :" + line);
        System.out.println("Output  :" + format(line));
    }
    
}
```

Test 1:

```
Input a combination : 023A
Input   :023A
Output  :23-A
```

Test 2:

```
Input a combination : 123A
Input   :123A
Output  :123-A
```